# Android app is not compatible with 4.1.2 even when supported sdk version is 14

Tags: android

I have launched an android app which supports devices with `sdk` version greater than `14` still its not compatible with a device having android version 4.1.2, which is a samsung device named gts7262, i have checked the app permissions and all are compatible with that device.

Please, help me in figuring out why play store is saying app is not compatible on that device. Am using following permissions and sdk version in my manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!-- Permission to access network state -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Permission to use camera - required by card.io-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Permission to vibrate - recommended, allows vibration feedback on scan -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<!--Permission needed to read default email addresses-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!--Permission needed to use internet on user's mobile-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!--Permission needed to trigger broadcast receiver for new incoming messages -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<!--Permission needed to retrieve OTP for verifying user mobile number -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<!--Permission needed to read user's contact for invite friends features-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<!--Permission needed to keep the processor from sleeping when GCM message is received -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--Permissions needed for the location tracking-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!--Permission needed to register GCM & receiving messages-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<!--Permission to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the GCM messages -->
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="app.windsleeve.momoe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<!-- Camera features - recommended by card.io-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: How can we without knowledge about your app?

Answer (score 1):

The GTS-7262, known as Samsung Galaxy Star Pro S7260, is described in GSM Arena as [lacking GPS functionality](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_star_pro_s7260-5749.php).

When you request:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I suggest you add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

Of course, if GPS and location features are not absolutely essential to your app, and you can employ graceful degradation in such cases. It depends on your app, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this maybe be the reason behind it

Comment: @user3090166 So please test it and report back. :-)

Comment: will definitely let you know once i push the app for the beta testing, right now we are focusing on new update of the app.